# How to run a task one day per week between given time window in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, automation, cron, periodic-task

I need to run a specific bash only on a given day of the week, between a given time window and only once.

For sake of clearity, in my case, these conditions are: "*running a bash script every Thursday between 5pm and 9pm only once*". The conditions can be simplified as "*running a bash script every Thursday after 5 pm*"

I looked at crontab and suceeded in running my script on a given day at a given hour

```
0 17 0 0 4 /path/my_ba.sh
```

Yet, I facing difficulty to introduce this notion of -- only once after a given hour --. Does any one knows a tool that could make such work?

---

PS: I think     I could get it done combining multiple bash and crontab lines but I'm looking for a more elegant solution.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Okay! Is there anyway to move the question or should I delete it?

Answer (score 1):

Set a cron job for 5pm on Thursday.
Sleep a random time between 0 and 3*3600 seconds.
Then execute your code.

```
0 17 0 0 4 bash -c 'sleep $((RANDOM%14400)); exec /path/my_ba.sh'
```